# Steam won't launch on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, steam

I know this question has been asked (and answered) multiple times, but I've tried all of the "solutions" suggested elsewhere, and none of them work.  Steam is the only app that I can't get working.

```
$ steam 
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2019-04-17 13:41:28] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

I have the NVidia 410 drivers installed.  Does anyone have any other ideas?  I've tried the following:

1. Removed ~/.steam and ~/.local/share/Steam/
2. Removing and installing Steam from both Ubuntu and steampowered.com
3. Installing all sorts of i386 packages
4. The instructions on this page: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have had a similar issue (not identical though). I had to remove both steam and my Nvidia drivers. Rebooted.

I then reinstalled my Nvidia drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, rebooted, and then installed Steam.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I did "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa; sudo apt remove nvidia-*" to remove the driver, then "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418" to install it (which updated me to the 418 driver).

Comment: Drop by in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room?_=302734240) sometime and leave a message @Fabby

Comment: I did the same as @lord_nimon - except using 'nvidia-driver-440'. This reinstalls everything that I unstalled - which is everything with nvidia*440:

Comment: `The following packages will be REMOVED: cuda-drivers* cuda-runtime-10-0* libnvidia-cfg1-440* libnvidia-common-440* libnvidia-decode-440* libnvidia-encode-440* libnvidia-fbc1-440* libnvidia-gl-440*
  libnvidia-ifr1-440* nvidia-compute-utils-440* nvidia-dkms-440* nvidia-driver-440* nvidia-kernel-common-440* nvidia-kernel-source-440* nvidia-utils-440*
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440*` - except cuda-drivers* cuda-runtime-10-0*` which I did not reinstall yet. After that reinstalled steam and everything worked.

Comment: I believe that the main issue is that when reinstalling it ALSO installed perviously uninstalled i386 packages though: `libnvidia-compute-440:i386
libnvidia-decode-440:i386
libnvidia-encode-440:i386
libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386
libnvidia-gl-440:i386
libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386`

Answer (score -2):

I have encountered this and the thing that worked for me was to uninstall steam and reinstall it. (It doesn't take very long at all, and does not affect downloaded games).  (Messing with Steam Linux or alt drivers must have caused this(?))

- uninstall steam (sudo apt remove steam)
- restart
- sudo apt install steam

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: (Oh, and you will have to re-add any custom steam libraries..)